# When I press enter for first raw_input python shell does not ask me for second raw_input

Tags: python

```
x = raw_input("What is your name?")
y = raw_input("What is your quest?")
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get:

```
What is your name?
```

When I answer and press enter the script ends without asking for `y`

Any ideas on why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you add a third `raw_input`?

Comment: Is that really the actual script you're running? I doubt this very much.

Comment: Did you reload the script in IDLE? It could be that you are running an outdated version of the script. What happens if you introduce a deliberate error?

Comment: Are you perhaps not doing this in a real terminal, like inside an IDE? If so, then open a Terminal and try it there. These two lines "must" work.

Comment: yes I am running it on IDLE shell Python 2.6.6 for OSX. when I press enter I get what is your name? So I type john and then I get >>> but no request for Y.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes I am a beginner and trying to figure out why such a simple task is not working

Comment: @nneonneo same thing if I add third raw_input

Comment: Wait, you get `>>>`? Are you pasting this in to the script window or something?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Here is an example of what I get as an error
>>> name = raw_input("W
   
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning single-quoted string
>>>

Comment: Don't enter both lines into the interpreter at once; the first `raw_input()` is executed *immediately* and you entered the second line as input to that line.

Comment: @nneonneo I am pasting it in a window titled python shell that opened when I started IDLE. Is that the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're *pasting* the script into the Python shell directly. This won't work: the second line will be treated as input to the first `raw_input`.

Instead, you should create a new script and use IDLE's Run Script functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what it was, I was pasting instead of running script

Answer (score 0):

I tried as follows using version 2.7.1 (on Windows 7) and it worked perfectly, did you forget to import sys?

```
import sys

x = raw_input("What is your name?")
y = raw_input("What is your quest?")
```

Note that I also ran this without sys and it worked perfectly, I have:

```
x = raw_input("What is your name?")
y = raw_input("What is your quest?")
```

If that is exactly what you have and it still does not work, I would suggest restarting your computer/python IDL and trying again, if it continues to fail try re-installing python being sure to use the most current stable build (2.7.1 for Windows).

Comment: P.S. If you are looking to learn Python, I am actually putting together a class for basic programming in Python, and would love to run it past someone before I teach it at my local community center. If you would like I can give a few lessons?

Comment: What do you mean take this offline? If you mean remove the post just click the remove button by the edit button. As for the class, my email is "StevenByrne255@gmail.com" Feel free to email me there and I can give you a rundown of the class idea (it is far from complete), and perhaps use an I.M. to transfer code and lessons.

Comment: @StevenByrne: when someone says to take something offline, they usually mean moving a conversation to a more private "offline" channel to avoid polluting the public "online" channel.

Comment: Ah, thank you; I'm a bit out-dated on the common slang of my generation(s).